# how to download latest version file in android?

Tags: android

I have prepared one sample application.When application install in devices download the file from server and store in local storage.When launch the application first check the file
version in server(file name like this filename_version(g_0.1)).when change the version that time only download the file and store in local, old version remove from local.

How to do this .Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you just want to have an md5 sum check. So thats the easiest way:
assume that you never downgrade the version on the server, then you save the md5 sum of your local file and request the one from the server. if its different you download the file.

otherwise if you really want to do this via the filename you could just get the filename from the server and then split up like this: `yourfile_1.0.9-dev` -> `{yourfile, 1, 0, 9, dev}` and you can easily compare major, minor and release version.